# Why Android system draws same content to canvas again and again

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

Here is a case for example:

I have TextView where I am setting "Hello" using setText(). I am setting same string again and again. I can see Surface update for each time  setting same text. I want to understand reason behind it. **should not system avoid this UI update?**

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the text again and again, the system obeys, as it should. How can the system know that it is not what you want? As a developer you are kind of supposed to know what you are doing.

Comment: There are some cases where you can not control for instance when we work on some state based architecture and there are 10 properties in the state and changing only one. Still it applies full state in view.